# Difference between loading time and running time in python?

Tags: python, time, module, loading

I am quoting a part of Python documentation:
"A program doesn’t run any faster when it is read from a .pyc or .pyo file than when it is read from a .py file; the only thing that’s faster about .pyc or .pyo files is the speed with which they are loaded."

I don't understand what does it mean when it says it doesn't affect the running time but the loading time? Could someone please explain it a little deep that I can understand completely?

Comment: The Python interpreter -- the program that actually _does stuff_ -- doesn't understand Python code as we write it. Instead, it converts it into a lower level version, known as "bytecode", and executes that. This conversion takes time but only needs to be done once, so the results are stored in a `.pyc` file for later use.

Comment: @katrielalex: please pose your responses in the form of an *answer*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps in converting the Python code you write to instructions the computer can understand:

1. A **compile step**.  The raw Python code is converted to Python [bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode).  This bytecode will be recognised by a Python interpreter on any operating system, on any hardware.  This is what is stored in a .pyo or .pyc file.
2. An **interpretation step**.  The Python interpreter, or if you prefer the Python virtual machine, interprets the bytecode and sends low-level instructions to the computer.  These low level instructions will be different between Linux and Windows, or between an Intel chip and an AMD, etc, so someone has to write a different interpreter for each type of system that Python can be run on.

When you run code from a .pyc file, step 1 has already been completed, so the execution goes straight to step 2.  But step 2 runs just as fast as it would run if you compiled it immediately before running it.  Whether the compile step slows down your code significantly depends on what your program does.  You should experiment to see how big a difference waiting for your code to compile takes, but if you are writing short scripts the difference will probably be unnoticeable.

Answer (score 3):

When you import a module `test.py`, Python must read the source and convert it into the bytecode Python can execute. This takes time, but Python will store this in `test.pyc`. This Bytecode is the result of breaking your code down into simpler terms able to run directly on the CPython Virtual Machine.

If you load `test.pyc`, Python doesn't need to compile your source into bytecode before running, so it takes slightly less time to start.

If you import the module `test.py` twice without modifying it or deleting the generated `test.pyc`, Python checks for the existence of `test.pyc` and loads it instead - so the performance benefit is automatic.

Comment: More exactly, `.pyc` files are only generated when a `.py` file is *imported*, not when it is run.